# Selenium unreachable browser exception in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, selenium

I try to find answers to my problem on the web and I didn't succeed. I am getting UnreachableBrowserException on IE selenium driver version 2.48 on wait after I am logout from my website and try to login. I tried to update my driver to 2.53 but it's wasn't helping (the 2.48 is more stable). I tried to kill all the process through CMD and other things that I read on the web, can you advise?

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
>       Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30
>   19:26:09'
>       System info: host: 'QA-2-Win8_1-64', ip: '192.168.0.235', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_91'
>       Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>       Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false,
>   pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false,
>   ignoreZoomSetting=true, handlesAlerts=true, version=11,
>   platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false,
>   elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=,
>   requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer,
>   initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:15488/, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false,
>   enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
>       Session ID: dd78bb1b-97ea-486c-bc59-c7e21dd272f1
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.isDisplayed(Unknown Source)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.elementIfVisible(ExpectedConditions.java:302)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$100(ExpectedConditions.java:41)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:288)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$10.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:285)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:238)
>         at com.automation.main.Page.waitForVisibility(Page.java:124)
>         at com.automation.main.LoginHelperPage.loginAdmin(LoginHelperPage.java:160)
>         at com.automation.main.TC18859ValidateTheSourceTypeAsRecordingChapterInSearchFieldOnThePastCourseLevel.loginCourses(TC18859ValidateTheSourceTypeAsRecordingChapterInSearchFieldOnThePastCourseLevel.java:171)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178)
>       Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:15488 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
>   failed: Connection refused: connect
>       Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30
>   19:26:09'
>       System info: host: 'QA-2-Win8_1-64', ip: '192.168.0.235', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_91'
>       Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:91)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
>         ... 39 more
>       Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:15488 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
>   failed: Connection refused: connect
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:144)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:90)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>         ... 40 more
>       Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
>         at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
>         at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
>         ... 53 more

Comment: Browser is closed in this case. Can you try with Firefox 46 ?. We have the same error with Firefox 47(latest version) .

Comment: it's happened to me only on IE , i used Firefox 47.0.1 with marionette